# Sass - Get one value from a property where multiple values are specified

Tags: css, sass

If I have a variable defined as such:

```
$item-padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
```

Is it possible with a Sass mixin to obtain the value of, say, just the `padding-left` value from the `$item-padding` variable?

Something like:

```
padding-left: get-value($item-padding, left);
```

Comment: is it not better to just separate it to $item-padding-top and $item-padding-left?

Comment: @ZivWeissman Yes, that was my first thought but it becomes overkill with so many variables if there is a tidy way of obtaining the individual values via a mixin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using Zurb Foundation framework, I found they've added a specific function to do this, called [get-side()](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass-functions.html#get-side).

> **get-side**
>
> Determine a top/right/bottom/right value on a padding, margin, etc. property, no matter how many values were passed in. Use this function if you need to know the specific side of a value, but don't know if the value is using a shorthand format.

The usage is as follows:

```
$padding-left: get-side($item-padding, left);
```

Answer (score 5):

Since your variable is actually a *space-separated* list, if you need to get the value `1rem` you could use the `nth(<list>, <index>)` function

```
padding-left: nth($item-padding, 2);
```